# Change position of container when hidde/visible some divs

Tags: html, css

I'm developing a tab functionallity using two buttons for making visible or not two divs ("div_agenda_hidden" and "div_calendar_hidden").
When the divs are displayed, their contents are seen one below the other.

**I need the divs to be shown in the same position and not underneath each other**.

This is "div_calendar_hidden".
[image]

And this "div_agenda_hidden".
[image]

As you see, the content is shown one below the other.
Any suggestion about the CSS attributes can be used?

If is needed I will post the code.
Thanks for reading!

Comment: how you are hiding the div on the selection please tell

Comment: Can you share relevant code or fiddle?

Answer (score 0):

Use `display:none;` instead of `display:hidden;`

From https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_display_visibility.asp:

> Hiding an element can be done by setting the display property to none. The element will be hidden, and the page will be displayed as if the element is not there [...] `visibility:hidden;` also hides an element. However, the element will still take up the same space as before. The element will be hidden, but still affect the layout

Answer (score 0):

Use `display: none;` and not `display: hidden;`.

`display: none;` will completely make your container disappear, no matter the rest of your CSS.

`display: hidden;` will just "masked" your container, like just a big white rectangle ;)